# rgrep doesn't search in specified directory

Tags: search, rgrep

According to the documentation :

> `(rgrep REGEXP &optional FILES DIR CONFIRM)`
>
> Recursively grep for `REGEXP` in `FILES` in directory tree rooted at `DIR`.
>
> [...]

But when I call it in some Elisp code like this :

`(rgrep "test" "*\\.org" "\\~/Org")`

It ends up neglecting the third argument `DIR` and instead uses the current directory.

The corresponding output and the `find` command of the above code is :

```
-*- mode: grep; default-directory: <current_directory> -*-
Grep started at Fri May  1 14:24:46
```

```
find . <exclude_expr> -type f \( -name \*\\.org \) -exec grep --color -i -nH --null -e test \{\} +
```

but the output I obtained interactively with `M-X rgrep`

```
-*- mode: grep; default-directory: ~/Org -*-
Grep started at Fri May  1 14:24:46
```

```
find . <exclude_expr> -type f \( -name \*\\.org \) -exec grep --color -i -nH --null -e test \{\} +
```

is expected.

Note: `GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.8, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2020-01-13`

Comment: Please see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't made `rgrep` work at the first time (got an error like `string-match("<c>" nil)` and still don't know why). I tried to escape unnecessarily the three arguments after reading [emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GrepMode#toc6). But the solution is given for GnuWin32...

Conclusion, when `rgrep` works, it's as expected: no need to escape anything. 
I'll ask about the error. No clue why it happens.

**EDIT**

1. By Inspecting the `rgrep` source code, `rgrep` use default directory when the given one is not a directory (in my case: syntax error).
2. [To prevent `string-match("<c>" nil)`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58210/rgrep-string-matchc-nil-error), one must call `(grep-compute-defaults)` before.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible that `rgrep` doesn't automatically expand DIR. Can you try if you have more success with something like that:

```lisp
(rgrep "test" "*\\.org" (expand-file-name "~/Org"))
```

Comment: It's not this, but you helped me find out the problem: I escaped unnecessarily the dir name.