# Custom made rgrep via ack stopped working

Tags: rgrep

I used to use the function below to call ack as a fast, recursive grep, but for whatever reason it stopped working. More precisely it returns no result. It probably happened when I updated Emacs or macOS, hard to say.

The ack is working from terminal without any issues.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it? I also considering alternatives, but hopefully not too slow for big folders.

```lisp
(defun my/rgrep ()
  (interactive)
  (if (executable-find "ack")
    (let* ((regexp (grep-read-regexp))
            (dir (read-directory-name "Base directory: " nil default-directory t))
            (command (concat "ack '" regexp "' " dir)))
      (unless (file-accessible-directory-p dir)
        (error (concat "directory: '" dir "' is not accessible.")))
        (compilation-start command 'grep-mode))
    ))
```

---

EDIT:
Sadly even rgrep doesn't work when evaluated as `(progn (grep-compute-defaults) (rgrep "foo" "*.txt" "/Volumes/RAM_Disk/test"))` where that folder has only one txt file with text "foo" it returns no matches. The generated find command below:

```bash
find . -type d \( -path \*/SCCS -o -path \*/RCS -o -path \*/CVS -o -path \*/MCVS -o -path \*/.src -o -path \*/.svn -o -path \*/.git -o -path \*/.hg -o -path \*/.bzr -o -path \*/_MTN -o -path \*/_darcs -o -path \*/\{arch\} \) -prune -o \! -type d \( -name .\#\* -o -name \*.o -o -name \*\~ -o -name \*.bin -o -name \*.lbin -o -name \*.so -o -name \*.a -o -name \*.ln -o -name \*.blg -o -name \*.bbl -o -name \*.elc -o -name \*.lof -o -name \*.glo -o -name \*.idx -o -name \*.lot -o -name \*.fmt -o -name \*.tfm -o -name \*.class -o -name \*.fas -o -name \*.lib -o -name \*.mem -o -name \*.x86f -o -name \*.sparcf -o -name \*.dfsl -o -name \*.pfsl -o -name \*.d64fsl -o -name \*.p64fsl -o -name \*.lx64fsl -o -name \*.lx32fsl -o -name \*.dx64fsl -o -name \*.dx32fsl -o -name \*.fx64fsl -o -name \*.fx32fsl -o -name \*.sx64fsl -o -name \*.sx32fsl -o -name \*.wx64fsl -o -name \*.wx32fsl -o -name \*.fasl -o -name \*.ufsl -o -name \*.fsl -o -name \*.dxl -o -name \*.lo -o -name \*.la -o -name \*.gmo -o -name \*.mo -o -name \*.toc -o -name \*.aux -o -name \*.cp -o -name \*.fn -o -name \*.ky -o -name \*.pg -o -name \*.tp -o -name \*.vr -o -name \*.cps -o -name \*.fns -o -name \*.kys -o -name \*.pgs -o -name \*.tps -o -name \*.vrs -o -name \*.pyc -o -name \*.pyo \) -prune -o  -type f \( -iregex \*.txt \) -exec grep -i -nH --null -e foo \{\} +
```

After more pondering on this, I found that there is also a problem with running rgrep or any alternative in tramp.

I think of making a universal my/rgrep function that will use default strategy like ack, and fallback to another strategy like ag and find/grep if the previous one wasn't found. Also making it work with tramp.

Because I already have defined config for ack that works well from the terminal I would put ack on the front of that list, but it shouldn't matter which one we put first.

Does anyone of you have this problem solved already, or at least have configured tramp to work well with rgrep?

Comment: Use `(elisp)Edebug` to learn what's happening.  Note that `(concat "ack '" regexp "' " dir)` is buggy.  Compilation commands are run via a shell, so use `C-h f shell-quote-argument`.  Currently you're assuming that single-quoting will be fine, so I imagine your command will just break if REGEXP contained a single quote, and DIR isn't escaped at all.

Comment: Did you try `rgrep` ?  `(progn (grep-compute-defaults) (rgrep "<regex>" "<file-glob>" "<directory>"))`. Remember to add the `(grep-compute-defaults)` if you call `rgrep` programmatically.

Comment: @phils thanks for mention that. This command used to work, but from time to time it might fail, but rarly so I kept using it. The problem is when I run this function it opens grep buffer with the command that it soupuse to run, but without any results, but when I copy it to the terminal it works and results are found.

Comment: @FirminMartin yes, I tried with plain rgrep, but I get no results as well. The generated command is ridiculously long so I can't even paste it here. Hard to say if generated command is correct because it's crazy long, complex and run forever when pasted to the terminal. This is why I wanted to adapt ack or similar in place of rgrep.

Comment: It's long because it maintains a list of extension to exclude. `rgrep` does work if you follow what I mentioned (otherwise you'll run into [this issue](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58210/rgrep-string-matchc-nil-error?rq=1). Show us the `rgrep` emacs-lisp snippet (not the generated command) ?

Comment: Just for clarity, because I inadvertantly missed out the keybinding, I meant to write `C-h i g (elisp)Edebug` in my first comment, which will take you to that node of the manual.

Comment: You might also try `which ack` from the terminal, and then use that absolute path explicitly in the elisp command, just to make sure it's *actually* running the same command as the terminal.

Comment: @FirminMartin The command I tried is `(progn (grep-compute-defaults) (rgrep "foo" "*.txt" "/Volumes/RAM_Disk/test"))`. Where this folder contains only one file pom.txt with the text "foo", but no matches found.

Comment: @phils I tested what ack is Emacs using via `(executable-find "ack")` it's the same as I use in terminal.

Comment: I updated the post with more information and output generated from suggested commands.

Comment: For some reason, your generated `find` command uses `-iregex \*.txt` which is wrong (even in my side), mine use `-name \*.txt` and it works. Maybe you can fix the issue by passing a regex at the second argument (*e.g.* `.*.txt`), but it's not the expected behaviour of `rgrep`. I'll take a look on the source code.

Comment: May I ask which version of emacs are you using ? Mine is `28.0.50`. I read the code source, and find out that `-name` is hardcoded in the function `rgrep-default-command`. You might have a look in it, or upgrade emacs. (I can't help for `ack`).

Comment: @FirminMartin I use emacs 26.3.

Comment: I `diff` the source code of `lisp/progmodes/grep.el` for emacs version `26.3` and `28.0.50 of 2020-10-16`. There are no substantial changes which can explain you have `-iregex` instead of `-name`. Please try with `emacs -Q` if you still have courage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for suggestions in comments, especially by Firmin Martin, I managed to find an answer to the problem. It turned out that the variable `find-name-arg` was set to `-iregex` which caused the issue in rgrep, no matter if used with ack or with regular `grep`. After brinding is back to default `-iname` the rgrep works fine.